# CSS3 Transition on audio player

Tags: html, css

Hello I am using the HTML5 audio element and I am having trouble with a transition for it. Right now I have a music icon and when the cursor hovers over it, it shows the whole audio player at once. What I want it to do is slowly show the whole audio player via CSS transition. Is this possible?

```css
.header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.heading {
  font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.player {
  width: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
}
.show:hover .hide {
  display: inline;
  width: 195px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p class="heading">Heading</p>
  <div class="show pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-music fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="player">
    <audio
     id="audioPlayer" 
     class="hide" 
     autoplay="true" 
     controls="true" 
     src="">
   </audio>
   </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to do transition on `.player` but on `:hover` you're changing width of `.hide`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `transition` coupled with `transform` to achieved some slick effect

```css
.header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.heading {
  font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
.hide {
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -o-transform: scale(0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.player {
  width: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
}
.show:hover .hide {
  display: inline;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
  width: 195px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p class="heading">Heading</p>
  <div class="show pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-music fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">Hover here</i>
    <span class="player">
        <audio id="audioPlayer" class="hide" autoplay="true" controls="true" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg">
        </audio>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome this worked out great the added animation was nice thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it but I guess this should work:

```
 .hide {
    width: 0px;
   -webkit-transition: width 2s;   
 }

 .show:hover .hide {
    width: 195px;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
 }
```

Is this what you need?